# Which is better to use `Int((n+1)/2)`, `round(Int, (n+1)/2)` or `Int((n+1)//2)`?

Tags: julia

I have a odd number `n` and want to use `(n+1)/2` as an array index. What is the best way to calculate the index? I just came up with to use `Int((n+1)/2)`, `round(Int, (n+1)/2))` and `Int((n+1)//2)`. Which is better or don't I need to too worry about them?

Comment: You may want to see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For better performance, you need integer division (`div` or `÷`) for that. `/` gives floating point results for integer arguments. `//` gives a `Rational` not an integer. So you need to write `div(n+1, 2)` or `(n+1) ÷ 2`. To type `÷` you can write `\div` and then press TAB on julia REPL, Jupyter notebook, Atom, etc.

Even if the dividend (n+1) is even, you need integer division to obtain an integer result directly, otherwise you need to convert the result to integer which will in turn be costly compared to the integer division.

You may also use *right bit shift operator* `>>` or *unsigned right bit shift operator* `>>>`, as *positive* integer division by `2^n` corresponds to shifting bits of that integer to the right n times. Although integer division by a power of 2 will be lowered to bit shift operation(s) by the compiler, the compiled code will still have an extra step if the dividend is a signed integer (i.e. Int and not UInt). **Therefore, using the right bit shift operators instead may give better performance, although this is *likely* to be a premature optimization and affects the readability of your code.**

The results of `>>` and `>>>` with negative integers will be different than that of the integer division (`div`).

Also note that using unsigned right bit shift operator `>>>` might save you from some integer overflow issues.

> div(x, y)
>
> ÷(x, y)
>
> The quotient from Euclidean division. Computes x/y, truncated to an
>   integer.

```
julia> 3/2 # returns a floating point number
1.5

julia> julia> 4/2
2.0

julia> 3//2 # returns a Rational
3//2  

# now integer divison
julia> div(3, 2) # returns an integer
1

julia> 3 ÷ 2 # this is the same as div(3, 2)
1

julia> 9 >> 1 # this divides a positive integer by 2
4

julia> 9 >>> 1 # this also divides a positive integer by 2
4
# results with negative numbers
julia> -5 ÷ 2
-2

julia> -5 >> 1 
-3

julia> -5 >>> 1
9223372036854775805

# results with overflowing (wrapping-around) argument
julia> (Int8(127) + Int8(3)) ÷ 2  # 127 is the largest Int8 integer 
-63

julia> (Int8(127) + Int8(3)) >> 1
-63

julia> (Int8(127) + Int8(3)) >>> 1 # still gives 65 (130 ÷ 2)
65
```

You can use `@code_native` macro to see how things are compiled to native code. Please do not forget more instructions does not necessarily imply being slower, although here it is be the case.

```
julia> f(a) = a ÷ 2
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> g(a) = a >> 1
g (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> h(a) = a >>> 1
h (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_native f(5)
    .text
; Function f {
; Location: REPL[61]:1
; Function div; {
; Location: REPL[61]:1
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    shrq    $63, %rax
    leaq    (%rax,%rdi), %rax
    sarq    %rax
;}
    retq
    nop
;}

julia> @code_native g(5)
    .text
; Function g {
; Location: REPL[62]:1
; Function >>; {
; Location: int.jl:448
; Function >>; {
; Location: REPL[62]:1
    sarq    %rdi
;}}
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    retq
    nopw    (%rax,%rax)
;}

julia> @code_native h(5)
    .text
; Function h {
; Location: REPL[63]:1
; Function >>>; {
; Location: int.jl:452
; Function >>>; {
; Location: REPL[63]:1
    shrq    %rdi
;}}
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    retq
    nopw    (%rax,%rax)
;}
```

Comment: How about `(n+1)>>1`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs added bit shift operators, the answer has become very long and complicated though. Also note that not every array has positive indices, so the effect of using bit shift operators to index arrays with negative indices (e.g. [`OffsetArrays.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/OffsetArrays.jl)) will be different than the Euclidean division.